# R : Updating a vector given a set of indices

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector (initialized to zeros) and a set of indices of that vector. For each value in indices, I want to increment the corresponding index in the vector. So, say 6 occurs twice in indices (as in the example below), then the value of the 6th element of the vector should be 2.

Eg:

```
> v = rep(0, 10)
> v
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> indices
 [1] 7 8 6 6 2
```

The updated vector should be

```
> c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0)
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0
```

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this without using loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `tabulate` is made for that

```
> indices = c(7,8,6,6,2);
> tabulate(bin=indices, nbins=10);
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rle` for this:

```
x <- rle(sort(indices))
v[x$values] <- x$lengths
v
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0
```