# R : Updating a matrix given a set of indices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix(initialized to zeros) and a set of indices. If the i'th value in indices is j, then I want to set the (j,i)th entry of the matrix to 1.

For eg:

```
> m = matrix(0, 10, 7)

> indices
[1]  2  9  3  4  5  1 10
```

And the result should be

```
> result
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

I asked a somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279074/r-updating-a-vector-given-a-set-of-indices/22279100?noredirect=1#22279100) a little while back, which used a vector instead of a matrix. Is there a similar simple solution to this problem?

Comment: That's nice. Its simpler than the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## OP's example data
m = matrix(0, 10, 7)
j <- c(2,  9,  3,  4,  5,  1, 10)

## Construct a two column matrix of indices (1st column w. rows & 2nd w. columns)
ij <- cbind(j, seq_along(j))
## Use it to subassign into the matrix
m[ij] <- 1
m
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#  [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the answer in your linked question can easily be adapted to suit this scenario too by using `sapply`:

```
indices <- c(2,  9,  3,  4,  5,  1, 10)
sapply(indices, tabulate, nbins = 10)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#  [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

For small datasets you might not notice the performance difference, but Josh's answer, which uses matrix indexing, would definitely be *much* faster, even if you changed my answer here to use `vapply` instead of `sapply`.